# Why the arabic characters encoding changed automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unicode, utf-8

I uploaded a website 7 days ago. The website contains Arabic Language and other languages also(in DATABASE). I used `<meta charset="UTF-8">` for encoding in php pages and the Database was also uploaded in UTF-8 Everything was fine and I edited the files and pages several times the last 7 days, everything was fine.
But it's changed automatically as you can see some queries from database below:

```
INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('2', 'es', 'EspaÃ±ol', '1');
INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('3', 'sq', 'Shqiptar', '1');
INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('4', 'ar', 'Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ©', '1');
INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('5', 'be', 'Ð±ÐµÐ»Ð°Ñ€ÑƒÑÐºÑ–', '1');
INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('6', 'bg', 'Ð±Ð°Ð»Ð³Ð°Ñ€ÑÐºÑ–', '1');
INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('7', 'ca', 'CatalÃ ', '1');
INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('8', 'zh-CN', 'ä¸­å›½ç®€ä½“', '1');
INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('9', 'zh-TW', 'ä¸­åœ‹å‚³çµ±', '1');
INSERT INTO `languages` VALUES ('10', 'hr', 'Hrvatski', '1');
```

and so on...

But it was fine before but now it's like this, I opened the SQL file in notepad still got the same result.  Please help! :'(

Comment: Are you saying this is a notepad issue? Or a phpmyadmin issue? Did you read _UTF-8 All The Way Through_?  I'm not sure what needs to be fixed in your question.

Comment: I don't know what's the issue because, last time when I uploaded the database and everything on the hosting it was working all fine, but when I changed the host uploaded my site to the new server done everything same as before. Languages turned into unknown symbols.

Comment: I recommend thoroughly reading the dupe link.  Specifically check the database/table charset settings.  Make no assumptions.

Comment: If it helps, the strings are mojibake with some unknown decoding of UTF-8 bytes. It would help you to know what that encoding is to see if it is incompatible with any processing along it's way back to UTF-8. Or, as the linked question says, rewrite it to use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: A shorter link that covers the issues, especially Mojibake and double-encoding, which you seem to have:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored